# 814 Dead Facebook Links to clean up or update. A little help?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, clean-up, facebook

wiki.developers.facebook.com got killed a while ago and there are a ton of dead links pointing there.  I flagged a few bad ones where the answer was only a dead link.  But there is a ton more fun to be had by filling up the mod queue with dead link flags.  Enjoy! A lot of the documentation didn't get moved but some of it did so the posts can be edited to reflect their new location.

[Facebook Dead Links Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/108618/)

Comment: developers.facebook.com but the url structure isn't the same so you'd have to search for it, if it even still exists.  Facebook is notorious for bad documentation.

Comment: Yet another reason to hate facebook.

Comment: Another query to run would be for all the comments that have this domain in it as well.

Comment: Please see [Bill's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101241/814-dead-facebook-links-to-clean-up-or-update-a-little-help/101247#101247) and my comment underneath. Most of these flags are great, but please take care.

Comment: Thanks for posting this offbysome, I will definitely work on updating these and loop in the Developer Relations team where I can.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just to help out a bit here, the data explorer is (as of this answer) about a month out of date...so let's use an updated list.

We added [a `url:` option](https://stackoverflow.com/search) to search a while back that you can use in cases like this:

[`url:"http://wiki.developers.facebook.com*"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A"http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.developers.facebook.com*") (`*` is a wildcard)

[See the current results here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A"http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.developers.facebook.com*")

Answer (score 7):

Please only flag the answers that contain **only** a dead link.  I already see some flagged posts that have a paragraph of text quoted along with the link for reference.  If you want to leave a comment on those to notify the author of the dead link that's fine, but we shouldn't be deleting them, so flagging is invalid.

Comment: I've been servicing the majority of these. The simple rule is "Does the context of this post completely vanish without the links?" If yes, then flag. If no, leave a comment telling the author that the links are broken. If you flag on a well written answer saying "the links are dead", I'll just leave a comment saying "Umm, the links are dead". Kindly, eliminate the middle man appropriately? :)

Comment: What is the post references several links that can be updated and a few links that are dead. Do I just update the links I can and suggest the author edit the other portions with dead link references?

Comment: @DSchultz: Yes, that would be much appreciated.